# Why does images.get_serving_url gives a 404 on dev server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404

I'm basicly uploading an image via XHR request and it's working on production but not in dev.

The link given by images.get_serving_url() returns a 404.

Link exemple : `http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/LCDrjov_QuwEE7peQTeAbg==`

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
    blob_info = upload_files[0]

    blob_key = blob_info.key()

    tmp_file = ProjectImage()
    tmp_file.image_blobkey = blob_key
    tmp_file.image_serve_url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key)
    tmp_file.project_id = int(self.request.get('project_id'))
    tmp_file.put()

    self.response.out.write("success")
```

**Edit :** I'm using Google App Engine Launcher bundeled with Python App Engine 1.8.9

---

**SOLUTION :**

The problem was that PIL was not found. I installed the 32bit version form the link provided in the App Engine doc. I needed the 64bit version which is not easy to find since it's all being replaced with pillow.

Here's a link to it : http://christianakesson.com/2013/4615

(Scroll down to the end of the post to get the binaries)

Comment: You can answer your question yourself and accept this answer to mark it as answered.

Comment: I don't have enough points yet :(